# Integrating a complex function over the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

We need to integrate the following:
$$\oint_C \frac{1}{z-a} \ dz$$

Where $|a| < 1$, and $C$ the unit circle ($e^{it} \ |  \ t \in [0,2\pi] $) . My idea was to find a geometric series, but I don't know how to find it for a function with two variables. Or does somebody have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure later in your studies you will do this via the Cauchy Integral Formula,
or via Cauchy's Residue Theorem or the like. For an elementary solution avoidng
these, write
$$\frac1{z-a}=\frac1{z}\frac1{1-a/z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^n}{z^{n+1}}$$
(geometric series). This series is uniformly convergent over the unit circle,
so we may interchange summation and integration to get
$$\int_C\frac{dz}{z-a}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n\int_C\frac{dz}{z^{n+1}}.$$
Then
$$\int_C\frac{dz}{z^{n+1}}=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-int}\,dt$$
which is $2\pi i$ for $n=0$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I choose $|a| > 1$, then the series is not convergent anymore. Is the integral than just $0$?

Comment: @Paul Indeed. This time, write $1/(z-a)$ as $-\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n/a^{n+1}$.